# MVVM Light, Ninject in a mostly notification area application

Tags: architecture, mvvm, ninject, mvvm-light

I need an application architecture advise.

I am building a .Net 4 WPF desktop application with notification area icon support.

Application has a few windows, that show up on startup, then get closed, and only the Notification Area icon remains.

The notification area icon is purely WPF control that I got from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_notifyicon.aspx) codeproject example.

Since my app should remain running even when all the windows are closed, I have set a

```
ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"
```

in App.xaml.

I will describe my idea of an architecture and startup mechanism, and you tell me where I am going wrong and correct me if possible.

In App.xaml.cs I create a Ninject `StandardKernel`, let's call it `appKernel` and load Ninject modules into it. At first only one interface is to be resolved by Ninject - a `heartbeatManager` instance. A HeartbeatManager is a class I am planing to use for:

a) Hosting my NotifyIcon instance as a field variable, so that it reamins visible as long as the class instance is in memory.

b) Implementation of shutdown event, that I will subscribe for in app.xaml.cs and shutdown the application explicitly, when the heartbeat class requests it.

At this point a `heartbeatManager` instance is created just left to hang in the memory.

In App.xaml I set the `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` so the MainWindow is created and shown. Following the MVVM Light ViewModelLocator pattern the MainWindow tries to resolve it's data context from the static ViewModelLocator instance defined in App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ViewModels:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
</Application.Resources>
```

ViewModelLocator instance is created and in the constructor it initializes another StandardKernel (*is there any other type of kernel I shout use at this point?*) that will be used to resolve the view model bindings. A MainWindow's view model is provided to satisfy the windows's request and the whole application continues to operate.

A very important implication, is that the hearbeatManger instance is bound to an interface definition in a singletone scope, so that view models that require it as a constructor parameter can resolve and get the already created instance. Will such dependency resolution work, if the view model and the heartbeatManager are loaded in a different kernels? If not, how can I solve this problem?

Is the above planned scenario any good architecture-wise, is it implementable in code, or have I made a mistake when I was thinking through the architecture?

Comment: I am having a hard time figuring out what the actual problem here is.  You talk about application shutdown, and having instances hang in memory, but you haven't explained why you're worried about these things.  The application class will stick around because it is created in the generated `Main` method, and your container/kernel should stick around if you place it in your app class, and classes you instantiate should stick around as long as the container does (especially singletons).  Why do you have two kernels/containers?  Also, this might be better for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Having two containers is the problem. I see that when I got down to try to implement all this. But how can I pass the kernel I create in app.xaml.cs to a viewmodel locator constructor, to avoid creating a second kernel for viewmodel resolution?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're even letting any of your code know about the Kernel.  What is special about your app that requires your to use the Kernel directly (except at the top level)?  It sounds like you might be using it as a Service Locator, when it is really designed to be used for Dependency Injection.  Is it just that you're having a problem figuring out how to get the container/kernel to satisfy `DataContext`, which is `Object`, and doesn't allow you to define view specific attributes?

Comment: I use ninject as a service locator in a viewmodel locator class as discribed here: http://kellabyte.com/2010/08/23/use-ninject-to-decouple-discovery-of-your-viewmodels-in-mvvmlights-viewmodellocator/

Comment: Is it the wrong way of locating my view models? I have almost implemented the above discribed architecture, the only problem remains, is how do pass the kernel, that I create in the top-level to a viewmodellocator constructor.

Comment: See [this article describing why you shouldn't use the Service Locator pattern in application code](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx).  The code you linked tries to solve two problems: Bind specific view models to views, and switch between design time and run time component versions.  You can build that logic directly into the app code where you create your kernel, and just use the same kernel for all your code.  See [the NInject Wiki Tutorials](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Why-Use-Ninject%3F)

Comment: In particular: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel and https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Providers%2C-Factory-Methods-and-the-Activation-Context .  You probably should simply constructor your views by using the factory method solution to set the `DataContext`, at the bottom of that second page.

Comment: I've gone through the same rigors, and come up with weird complex architectures that had similar failings (Castle.Windsor, using "typed factories" all over the place). This solution I am suggesting is much simpler to understand, implement, and maintain :) Of course, assuming I am not misunderstanding the challenges in this design problem...

Comment: Ok, binding ToMethod makes sense. My View constructor just requests a ViewModel and the kernel, that I create in app.xaml.cs, provides it implicitly. Thank you. ViewModelLocator is a default class that is created when one adds MVVMLight through NuGet. I guess an author of MVVMLight framework uses an anti-pattern himself.

Comment: Just one last question - In my View's constructor, how do I request a view model to set as a data context, given that the correct view model is "prepared" in the kernel? I have tried to resolve it as a constructor argument, but I get the run-time exception about the view not having the default constructor.

Comment: Keep in mind the service locator pattern being an anti-pattern is an opinion, and isn't entirely universal.  For example, most DI containers *use* the service locator pattern under the hood.  The point of using such a container is to abstract you from having to do anything but pure DI.  And several of those containers suggest you avoid mixing SL with DI in your application itself, because they've gone to a lot of trouble to abstract the SL container for you.

Comment: One option is to use property injection (which simply forwards its setter to `DataContext`).  Another is to register your views in the container rather than the view models, and to use the `ToMethod` solution: E.g. `Bind<MainView>().ToMethod(context => new MainView() { DataContext = new MainViewModel() });`.  The second is closer to what I've had in mind, though it depends on where your abstractions lie, and how your views get created/used.  Can't see your code, so can't tell you which is better :)

Comment: You have answered my question Merlyn. Thank you very much. You should teach at the university when you have a free time. Very good at explaining stuff =)

Comment: Glad I could help.  Is there a particular part that was most useful here?  I'm having a hard time figuring out how to turn this into a solid Q and solid A, for future visitors with the same question.

Comment: The answer would be like this: Don't use two kernels. Use one, but have a module to resolve your views. Use ToMethod for contextual binding of both ViewModels in case of Design and Runtime, and to bind ViewModels to a corresponding views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...At this point a heartbeatManager instance is created just left to hang in the memory...

If it is registered with your kernel, it isn't any magic that causes it to hang in memory - it will stick around as long as the kernel/container does.  That container should probably be a member of your App class, since your app class sticks around as long as the (compiler generated) `Main` method does, and you should dispose it on app shutdown anyhow.

> ...Following the MVVM Light ViewModelLocator pattern the MainWindow tries to resolve it's data context from the static ViewModelLocator instance defined in App.xaml...

I'm not sure this will mix well with NInject.  It is a Dependency Injection container, not a Service Locator container (even though it uses one under the hood).  The main purpose of NInject (and similar frameworks) is to avoid requiring you to use the Service Locator pattern, and instead to inject all your dependencies.

> ...ViewModelLocator instance is created and in the constructor it initializes another StandardKernel...

Unless your scenario is quite complicated (which it really isn't for this app), then I suggest sticking to a single NInject kernel.

**Suggested Solution**

The view model locator class itself doesn't do much for you other than let you split up your initialization logic, and do selective initialization depending on whether you're in design mode or runtime mode.  You could achieve the same with NInject modules (which [the view model locator article you linked in comments already uses](http://kellabyte.com/2010/08/23/use-ninject-to-decouple-discovery-of-your-viewmodels-in-mvvmlights-viewmodellocator/)).

I suggest that instead of using a view model locator, you specify *all* your components in your module class, and do the `IsInDesignMode` logic in the `Load` method.

This might be a bit tricky with MVVM though, since the view model needs to bind to an `object` property you didn't create, and can't annotate.

There are a few ways to solve this directly in NInject, instead of resorting to a service locator:

- Use Dependency Injection on your view, making it require a view model.
  If this doesn't work using constructor injection (as you mentioned in your comments), use property injection instead, with a custom property that forwards its setter to `DataContext`.
- Use [NInject factory methods](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Providers%2C-Factory-Methods-and-the-Activation-Context) (`ToMethod`) to create your view, and bind the view model to the view in each factory method.
  E.g. `Bind<MainView>().ToMethod(context => new MainView() { DataContext = new MainViewModel() });`

If you can, I'd go for the second method.  This way your view doesn't have to handle data binding, and doesn't have to have any code behind.  It is also simple to understand,  would let you avoid having to register both views and view models in the kernel, and would let you avoid making any sort of well known interface for your view model.